# Trying to pass variable from input radio to PHP via jQuery.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a html table created by a php code. The table should be generated by an sql query that depends on a variable from a radio input selector, but somehow i can't pass that variable via jQuery.post(). I made a simple version that has the same issue so I hope someone can help me with that:

test.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[name$='selectOP']").on("change", function() {
            var op = $(this).val();
            $.post('ajax.php', {varphp: op});   
            $("#div1").load('ajax.php', function(){             
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<body>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="110" name="selectOP" id="selectOP">110  </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="115" name="selectOP" id="selectOP">115  </label>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
    $var= "Something";
    echo $var;
    //$varphp = $_POST['varphp'];
    //echo $varphp;
?>
```

So, with the two last lines of ajax.php commented, code successfully runs and the var $var loads inside div1. But if i uncomment those lines, apparently the code stops, and nothing is loaded on div1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling $.post where you pass the argument and then calling load with no arguments. Of course you can't get $_POST['varphp'] when you call 'load' because you are not passing this variable.

you must use one of them.
you can do with this:

```
$.post('ajax.php', {varphp: op}, function(data){ $("#div1").html(data); }, 'html' );
```

or

```
$("#div1").load('ajax.php', {varphp: op});
```

but not both

thus, your code can be

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("input[name$='selectOP']").on("change", function() {
        var op = $(this).val();
        $.post('ajax.php', {varphp: op}, function(data){ $("#div1").html(data); }, 'html' ); 
    });

});
```

or

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("input[name$='selectOP']").on("change", function() {
        var op = $(this).val();
        $("#div1").load('ajax.php', {varphp: op}); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('ajax.php', {varphp: op});   
$("#div1").load('ajax.php', function(){             
$});
```

These two lines are actually making two separate ajax requests, which means the server will pick them up separately. Only the first one has a POST parameter, and only the second one sets the content of the DOM object.

Try something like this:

```
$("#div1").load('ajax.php', {
  varphp: op
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good practice I like is to use AJAX w/ deferred promises. You can try converting your code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post', // you can switch to GET, POST, etc.
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: {varphp: op},
})
.done(function(data) {
  $('#div1').html(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
  // if your code fails, you can see the errors here in the console
  console.log(data);
})
.always(function(data) {
  // do something every time
});
```

The codes within the `done`, `fail`, or `always` callback functions will run depending on whether the AJAX call is a success, fail, or neither respectively. With this, you can troubleshoot your code easily as well, especially when the AJAX call error'd out (look inside the `fail` function).